# How do I make a text bot in a shell (preferably repl.it) using the dialogflow python api?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a simple chatbot in my repl.it shell, but it errors, saying that it "Could not automatically determine credentials.", I have looked over it many times, and can't figure out how to do it. In addition, I might have other things wrong but I can't tell since I can't get past this error.
If anyone can help me with this, or if you have an example that I can follow, that would be great
https://repl.it/@RyandaKing/ThoughtfulWorrisomeQuadrant

```
import dialogflow
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument

DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'newagent-1-rhjebl'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'newagent-1-rhjebl-29ae80f7e64d.json'
SESSION_ID = '110497386060607202274'
text_to_be_analyzed = "Hello"
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
try:
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
except InvalidArgument:
    raise
print("Query text:", response.query_result.query_text)
print("Detected intent:", response.query_result.intent.display_name)
print("Detected intent confidence:", response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence)
print("Fulfillment text:", response.query_result.fulfillment_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you improperly use the private key contained by `.json`. As described [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup#using_the_key) you should define the environment variable having the value of `.json` key file path.

Assuming that the `.py` and `.json` files are in the same directory run it like this.

```
$ cd path/to/app
$ env 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=newagent-1-rhjebl-29ae80f7e64d.json' python3 app.py
```